# How to do a Level Transition on PC

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

I've been searching around but there is no guide on how to do a Level Transition in Injustice: Gods Among Us. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While standing with your opponent's back to the area which activates the transition (some edges of some levels, as far as I've seen) hold BACK and press HEAVY ATTACK (default control scheme for me using an XBox controller on PC was Back + A).